# Google Analytics initial referral lost

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api, universal-analytics, referrals

We have Universal Analytics installed on our main domain (site.com) and landingpages (landing.site.com). In real-time tracking, we see activity for both domains, so that works fine.

On our landingpages, people start the signup process by filling in a form, that does a post to our main domain, where they can continue the signup process.

**Now the strange thing is:**
When people fill in the form and land on our main domain, this traffic is shown as "Referral" in GA acquisition reports, with the landingpage as referral. *This behavior is incorrect, as the refferal leading to this landingpage should be shown here, instead of the landingpage itself.*

Due to this, we also see incorrect conversion rates in Adwords (as also the initial Adwords referral information is lost).

We already added our landingpage domain to the "referral exclusion list" in analytics. Adding _setDomainName is for Classic Analytics only, so that's not going to work for Universal Analytics.

Any idea what's going on, and how we can fix this?

Hope you can help, thanks!

Robin

Comment: You'll need to implement [Cross domain tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain) using the [Decorate HTML Form method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#decorateforms).

Comment: Or configure the cookie to be set on '.site.com', so the cookie works across both hostnames.

Comment: When setting up your tracking code, are you specifying a domain name or "auto" like so? `ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end adding the domain to excluded referrals was sufficient. If you do want to track traffic between excluded referrals, you can use utm params to have this traffic show up in your reports.

Answer (score 0):

There is `cookieDomain` option in Universal Analytics and you can use it as a replacement for `_setDomainName`. So, code on your landingpages could be:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
    cookieDomain: 'site.com'
});
```